# Why is numpys covariance totally different then mine?

Tags: python, numpy, covariance

I calculate my covariance with following formula:

```
np.dot(X_zero_mean, X_zero_mean.T) / (X_zero_mean.shape[0] -1)
```

and compare it to

```
np.cov(X_zero_mean.T)
```

I both print the resulting matrices to console and create a figure out of them, but they are not the same. Why? Could it be that cov avoids some numerical error, that is happening with my above formula?
First one is my covariance, second one is the numpy cov:
[image]

Comment: Can you share your input matrices if possible?

Comment: Not sure if useful... It's a 38*4080 matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your exact matrices it's difficult to tell, but I would guess that it's because you're taking the transpose of the matrix before passing it to `np.cov`. That would also explain why numpy's result looks like it's of much higher dimension than yours. `np.cov(X.T)` is equivalent to `np.dot(X.T, X)`, not `np.dot(X, X.T)`.

Comment: Leaving the tranpose away it is still completely off. Is the formula I am using wrong?

Comment: Please update your post with the results using `np.cov(X_zero_mean)`. Then we might be able to help answer this question.